# Evalute the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0, 1]}f dm$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

1. For each $x \in [0, 1]$, let

   $$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
       \frac{1}{n},& \text{if } x=\frac{k}{n}, \text{for some }k,n\in \mathbb{N} &\text{with } \ g.c.d(k, n)=1\\
       0,              & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$$

Evaluate the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0, 1]}f dm$.

2. For each $x \in [0, 1]$, let

   $$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
       x^2,& \text{if } x=\frac{1}{2^n},\text{for some  }n \in \mathbb{N}\\
       x^3 , &\text{if } x=\frac{1}{3^n},\text{for some  }n \in \mathbb{N}\\
       x^4,              & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$$

Evaluate the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0, 1]}f dm$.

**My work**: For question (1) I consider two partitions $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ and $\mathbb{Q^c} \cap [0, 1]$ then I get $L(p,f)=U(p, f)=0$ and the result of the integration is zero.(check this answer) but how to approach the 2nd question. please help to understand.

Comment: For 1, the Lebesgue integral is $0$ since $f=0$ a.e. (it's only nonzero on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, which has measure 0). For $2$, similarly, $f=x^4$ a.e. and $f\geq0$, so you can just compute $\int_{[0,1]}x^4dx$ (I think, I'm not quite sure).

Comment: yes, but how to do 2nd one @ Moya

Comment: I edited the above. If you take $g(x)=f(x)-x^4$, then, $g=0$ a.e. $\Rightarrow \int_{[0,1]}gdm = 0 \Rightarrow \int_{[0,1]}fdm = \int_{[0,1]}x^4dx$